# file_get_contents not working for a php file

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have the page referenced in the URL below using document.write in javascript to print out on the page a JSON string.

Im trying with the code below to get that string in php and decode it. The code works fine when Im trying to get a .json file, but is empty when I try a php file. My f_open is set to "On".

```
 <?php
 $string = file_get_contents("http://10.2.114.62/cam/api.php/PAGE/dashboard");
 $json_a = json_decode($string, true);
 print_r($json_a);
 ?>
```

Comment: What do you get when you visit http://10.2.114.62/cam/api.php/PAGE/dashboard? An empty page?

Comment: nope, the json as text.

Comment: ok then check for json_decode errors first by using json_last_error() before print_r($json_a) (check if there is an error while decoding - just to make sure that the json is valid)